# java, как в массив записать список директорий/файлов отсортированый Операционной системой

Tags: java, файлы

язык программирования - java
Суть задачи: нужно записать в масив **File[]** список файлов/директорий "в том порядке, в котором он отсортировай операционной системой". То есть, если в ОС Windows список директорий отсортированый по дате создания, то и в массив нужно так же залить данные.

Список файлов беру File[] files = dir.listFiles(); где dir - переменная File, что хранит ссилку на директорию с которой пытаюсь взять список файлов.

Comment: `в ОС Windows список директорий отсортированый по дате создания` - на NTFS такого быть не может, там всегда сортировка по имени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список файлов/директорий, отсортированый по дате создания, (в порядке возрастания):

```
File[] sortedFiles = Files.list(Paths.get("C:\\Windows")).sorted((o1, o2) -> {
    try {
        return Files.readAttributes(o1, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime()
                .compareTo(Files.readAttributes(o2, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}).map(Path::toFile).toArray(File[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedFiles));
```